# needed to show Toastr Notification jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

guys, i am using Toastr Notification (jquery Plugin) 
whenever user updates record it shows notification of 
success alert using plugin but problem is 
that whenever I update record 
it shows error in the console of the browser

```
**Uncaught ReferenceError: success is not defined**

my alert code is
<?php
if($update_recored)
{
?>
<script>
Command: toastr[success]("Record Updated", "Successfully Updated");
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no knowledge of Php but i can help you in jquery.

Please see below code.

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    toastr.success("Record Updated", "Successfully Updated");
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Your codes works fine but can you please debug mine once

Answer (score 1):

And if you want show it by time use below code.

Step 1: Add Cdn files

Step 2: Show toast whe page is ready with jquery

```
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.4/toastr.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/back/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.4/toastr.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      toastr.success('Options saved', 'Thanks for help John', {timeOut: 5000})
      });
    </script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.4/toastr.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/back/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.4/toastr.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$( "#myButton" ).click(function() {
  toastr.success('Options saved', 'Thanks for help Cemil', {timeOut: 5000})
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```